# Can we get rid of the behavior tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [behavior](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) tag doesn't seem useful to me. Here's the excerpt:

> Questions about the behavior of other people around you, as well as how you should behave in certain situations and circumstances.

Everyone has behavior. Behavior can mean anything. At the moment, this tag is essentially means "questions about interpersonal skills." The tag is so broad it isn't very useful.

Let's remove it.

Comment: Is that what interpersonal skills basically is? *How do I act in this situation?*

Comment: @Zizouz212 yeah, exactly! This tag adds no information that isn't already communicated by the fact that the question is asked on this site. Let's get rid of it, and do it yesterday.

Comment: Besides, the tag isn't even spelt right... It's supposed to be behaviour :P

Comment: @Hamlet I rejected an edit of yours removing the tag; I had overlooked your comment referencing this meta.

Comment: @SQB I just resubmitted the edit. And there are a lot of edits waiting in the review queue

Answer (score 3):

With questions such as [How to blow your nose in public](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/360/16), and then this [How do I make friends with service staff at restaurants/bars?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/138/16)... It's difficult to see what the tag means.

## <strike>Burn it with fire!</strike> Get the hose! It's burned down!

(I'm going to start editing the tag out of the question, and placing more appropriate tags if needed)

Comment: I don't have edit privileges... Hmm... People with 1k rep unite!